# Como crear una clase que me retorne un consulta a Mysql en formato Combobox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

estoy entrampado y necesito un poco de ayuda:
Quiero crear una clase que haga una consulta y la retorne para pasarlo a un combobox
en C# windows form,la idea es llamar a esta clase, donde se requieran estos datos.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("leeciudades", conexion.Conectar());
        // Acá se cargan las empresas que estan creadas en el combobox
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        cmb_ciudades.ValueMember = "c_indice";
        cmb_ciudades.DisplayMember = "c_nombre";
        cmb_ciudades.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: ¿Qué es el "*formato Combobox*"?

Comment: ???
No entiendo el comentario!

Comment: Permíteme preguntar de otro modo César: ¿Qué entiendes por "formato Combobox"?

Comment: Hola buen dia...en ninguna parte hablo de "formato combobox", si no que del control combobox...
Me refiero al control  Combobox o lista desplegable.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una clase en C# que tenga un método estático que realice la consulta a la base de datos y retorne un DataTable con los resultados. Luego, puedes llamar a este método desde cualquier parte de tu aplicación para llenar tu ComboBox. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podrías estructurar esa clase:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; // Asegúrate de tener la referencia a MySql.Data en tu proyecto

public class ConsultasBD
{
    // Método estático para realizar la consulta y retornar un DataTable
    public static DataTable ObtenerCiudades()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("tu_cadena_de_conexion"))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("leeciudades", conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Maneja excepciones según tu necesidad
            Console.WriteLine("Error al obtener ciudades: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo, reemplaza "tu_cadena_de_conexion" con la cadena de conexión a tu base de datos MySQL.

Luego, desde tu formulario de Windows Forms, puedes llamar a este método estático para llenar tu ComboBox de la siguiente manera:

```
DataTable ciudades = ConsultasBD.ObtenerCiudades();

cmb_ciudades.ValueMember = "c_indice";
cmb_ciudades.DisplayMember = "c_nombre";
cmb_ciudades.DataSource = ciudades;
```

Comment: La respuesta no es mala, pero es el mismo codigo que esta en la pregunta... lo que pasa es que la pregunta es malisiama, cual es el punto? basicamente, le dijiste mete tu codigo en una clase estatica (que tampoco se porque es estatica, pero bue)... lo otro, porque usar algo tan antiguo como un datatable?????

Comment: **1. Clase estática:** Propuse una clase estática para encapsular la funcionalidad de consulta a la base de datos. La elección de hacerla estática es una cuestión de diseño y puede tener ventajas en algunos casos. Al hacerla estática, no es necesario crear una instancia de la clase para utilizar el método, lo que puede simplificar el código de llamada. Sin embargo, esto depende de la estructura y necesidades específicas de la aplicación. No es una elección obligatoria, y se puede utilizar una clase no estática si se prefiere.

Comment: **2. Uso de DataTable:** Tienes razón en señalar que el uso de DataTable puede ser considerado "antiguo" en comparación con las alternativas más modernas como los objetos de entidad y los ORM (Object-Relational Mapping). La elección de utilizar un DataTable o una estructura de datos específica depende del contexto y los requisitos de la aplicación.

Comment: Estimado gracias por la ayuda, tengo que indicar que soy nuevo en C#, si la pregunta el malisima como dice el colega. Lo siento, pero no la veo incorrecta.
Solo busco recursividad, tener una clase que me retorne las ciudades (o cualquier dato) para que se cargue en cualquier control de Windows Form de C# 

no dudo que deben haber mejores formas, pero actualmente es la que manejo.
Gracias por la ayuda del código, voy a  probar...creo que me ayuda muchísimo.